# I am trying to create a random load out generator using python. However I am having problems with rerunning the program using user input

Tags: python

```
import random
Primary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]
Secondary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]
print (random.choice(Primary))
print (random.choice(Secondary))
while True: 
    answer = str(input('Run Again? (Y/N): '))
    if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
        print ("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        random()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: `random` is a module, not a function. What are you trying to do with `random()`?

Comment: I was hoping that having random() I could make the script restart by choosing y when it asks. This is because when I tried too use main() with def main: at the top it did not work as it would say that random cannot be defined in line 5.

Comment: @Carcigenicate how come you can edit a post to be all code?

Comment: @zr0gravity7 Anybody can edit it after the fact afaik. You just can't post a question that's all formatted code to begin with. If you aren't able, it may be a privilege gained through rep.

Answer (score 0):

Move the printing of the random chosen weapons inside your loop, so that the code runs on each iteration.

```
import random
Primary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]
Secondary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]

while True: 
    print(random.choice(Primary)) # move the printing of the random choice inside the loop
    print(random.choice(Secondary))

    answer = input('Run Again? (Y/N): ') # input() already returns a str
    if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
        print ("invalid input.")
    if answer == "n": # break out of loop if user inputs "n"
        break
    # otherwise continue iterating

print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
Primary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]
Secondary = ["QBZ-83", "AK-47 CW", "Groza", "Krig 6", "XM4", "FARA 83", "FFAR 1","C58", "CR-56 AMAX", "Oden", "RAM-7", "AK-47 MW" ,"AN-94", "M4A1", "M13", "Kilo 141", "FN Scar 17", "FR 5.56", "AS VAl", "Grau 5.56", "FAL", "Bullfrog" ,"AK-74", "Milano 821", "Nail Gun", "KSP 45", "LC10", "MAC-10", "PPsh-41", "CW MP5", "P90", "Fennec", "MW AUG", "MP7", "Striker 45", "Uzi", "MW MP5", "PP19 Bizon", "ISO", "Streetsweeper", "Gallo SA12", "Hauer 77", "Origin 12 Shoutgun", "725", "Model 680", "R9-0 Shotgun", "VlK Rogue", "JAK-12", "Stoner 63", "M60", "RPD", "MG 82", "Bruen Mk9", "MG34", "PKM", "FiNN LMG", "M91", "SA87", "Holger-26", "M16", "DMR 14", "CARV.2", "CW AUG", "Type 63", "R1 Shadowhunter", "Crossbow", "SKS", "EBR-14", "Kar98k", "MK2 Carbine", "SP-R 208", "LW3 - Tundra", "Swiss K31", "Pellington 703", "ZRG 20mm", "M82", "Rytec AMR", "HDR", "AX-50", "Dragunov", "Riot Shield", "Diamatti", "CW 1911", "Magnum", "AMP63", "Renetti", "MW 1911", ".50 GS", "M19", "X16", ".357", "Sykov", "RPG-7", "Cigma 2", "M79", "Strela-P", "JOKR", "PILA", "Combat Knife", "E-Tool", "Wakizashi", "Ballistic Knife", "Baseball Bat", "Machete", "Sledgehammer", "Kali Sticks", "Knife", "Dual Kodachis"]
print (random.choice(Primary))
print (random.choice(Secondary))
while True: 
    answer = str(input('Run Again? (Y/N): '))
    if answer not in ('y','Y','n','N'):
        print ("invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y' or answer == 'Y':
        print (random.choice(Primary))
        print (random.choice(Secondary))
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```